# Unity: Add Button Script to 3D gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

I'm trying to add the Unity Button Script to a 3d gameObject. When I tried this by adding it onto a cube, I can't get the desired behaviours. How can I get the 3d object to work like a button? In particular the highlighting colors, the click events. I was speculating that perhaps it uses the wrong raycaster, and if the raycaster specificaiton is changed some how it would work? Does anyone have a good enough understanding of the source code to explain if this is possible, and if so what I would need to do to achieve this? Thanks.

Rik

Comment: This tutorial may help you and others https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHEG95vrO_Q

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by using `OnMouseDown()` function. Here is the link [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to add the image script along with the button script.